# How to manage mouse right/center click with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The [clickable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures) Modifier in Jetpack Compose doesn't seem to have a way to differentiate the type of button in case of Mouse input

Do you know how to manage this use cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found two ways to get this working for me.

First was using `pointerInput`, where you have to be careful to consume the event otherwise it can be handled twice:

```kotlin
    modifier = Modifier
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            awaitPointerEventScope {
                val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                if (event.type == PointerEventType.Press &&
                    event.buttons.isSecondaryPressed) {
                    event.changes.forEach { e -> e.consume() }
                    // on-click logic here
                }
            }
        }
```

Second was using the new experimental API:

```kotlin
    modifier = Modifier
        .onClick(
            matcher = PointerMatcher.mouse(PointerButton.Secondary),
            onClick = {
                // ...
            }
        )
```

In both cases I have some quirks where the button handles events slightly outside the button which there are [further workarounds](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues/2348) for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm managed to find a solution building a custom modifier:

```kotlin
    private fun Modifier.notifyRightClick(block: () -> Unit): Modifier =
        composed {
            val blockState = rememberUpdatedState(block)

            pointerInput(Unit) {
                while (currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
                    awaitPointerEventScope {
                        val event = awaitPointerEvent(PointerEventPass.Initial)
    
                        if (event.buttons.isSecondaryPressed) {
                            blockState.value()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This executes the code passed as `block` if the mouse right click is pressed on the UI element where the modifier is applied

Comment: It seems to call the block constantly if you keep holding down the mouse button as well. :/

Comment: @Hakanai interesting, this code call the block only one time in my test. I'm testing with Windows Subsystem for Android on Windows 11. Where are you testing this? Any demo code to use?

Comment: Compose desktop running on Windows 10

Comment: This question was referred to Android, there are differences between the two Compose

Comment: If your right click handler does something which changes the UI somehow, it's possible that even if you are holding down the mouse button, the events won't get delivered because the button in the UI isn't receiving them anymore. In my case, the only visible effect is toggling the presentation of the button, but the button's still there in the same position and might even be the same object. It's unfortunately really hard to tell with Compose though.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! In my case I had to add '''event.changes.forEach { e -> e.consume() }''' before '''blockState.value()''' in order to block main action from execution (Samsung, Android 13, both left and right mouse buttons do the same by default).